# jquery code works on jfiddle, but not on my pc?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to get this fiddle to work, [Here's a link to the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4rkkksmd/4/)

I've copied it into a html document, yet it doesn't work.
and that's my code, what am I doing wrong? am I missing some source?

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style>
tr.btn {
    cursor: pointer;
}

table, tr, td {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
table tr.hidden td .slide {
    display: none;
}
table tr.hidden td {
    height: 0;
}
</style>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
$('tr.btn td').click(function(){
    $('tr.hidden .slide').toggle(200)
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<table border="1">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>1</th>
            <th>2</th>
            <th>3</th>
            <th>4</th>
            <th>5asdfasdfasdf</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr class="btn">
            <td colspan="5">Click me</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="hidden">
            <td>
                <div class="slide">
                    asd
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="slide">
                    asd
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="slide">
                    asd
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="slide">
                    asd
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="slide">
                    asd
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="hidden">
            <td>
                <div class="slide">
                    asd
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="slide">
                    asd
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="slide">
                    asd
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="slide">
                    asd
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="slide">
                    asd
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="hidden">
            <td>
                <div class="slide">
                    asd
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="slide">
                    asd
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="slide">
                    asd
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="slide">
                    asd
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="slide">
                    asd
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>a</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>c</td>
            <td>d</td>
            <td>e</td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DOM is not fully loaded when your `click` handler is read (the referenced HTML elements don't yet exist).

Use a DOM ready event handler function to ensure that the DOM is fully loaded, which ensures all the HTML elements exist before the function is read.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('tr.btn td').click(function(){
        $('tr.hidden .slide').toggle(200)
    });

});
```

See:  http://api.jquery.com/ready/

It's working in the jsFiddle, because jsFiddle automatically handles this for you.  Note the `onload` option under Frameworks & Extensions in the left-hand pane.

Answer (score 3):

JSFiddle conveniently adds `$(document).ready()` for you. Your local example, however, does not, and the code therefore executes before the DOM is actually loaded. To remedy this, wrap your jQuery code in the document ready function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    ...
}):
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('tr.btn td').click(function(){
        $('tr.hidden .slide').toggle(200)
    });
})
```